# Proving a space is not complete by finding an absolutely convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, complete-spaces, absolute-convergence

For $ v ∈ l^2(\mathbb{N}, F) $ define

$$ ||v||_w=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |v_{[k]}|/2^k$$
as a norm,

Is $ l^2(\mathbb{N}, F) $ with the norm $||v||_w $   a complete space?

I am trying to find a series of vectors which is absolutely convergent, but is not convergent

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

i) We have 
$$\left|\sum a_kb_k \right| \leq \left(\sum |a_k|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum |b_k|^2\right)^{1/2}$$

Use this to show the question is not rubbish.

ii) Now find a sequence $v_n = (a_k)_{k=1}^{k=n}$ (depending on the weight function) such that $v_n$ converges to something in the new norm, but where the limit in not part of $\ell^2$.

*To construct the finite sequence, start by looking at $v_n =(a_k)_{k=1}^{k=n}$ where $a_k = 2^k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ - this one will not make the job (why?).
Now, modify the sequence slightly.*

---

You can do this!

Comment: I am having trouble finding the sequence

Comment: I added some lines that I hope helps.

Comment: Thank you, I see how the w-norm of the 2^L sequence would diverge, but wouldn't every series also diverge with the w-norm as every time you are adding on something bigger then before?